# jQuery jump menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make some code shorter and usable. Can someone look over the code I wrote and let me know if it's done correctly?  I think it is but it seems a little too simple.  The code allows a user to select a location form a drop down, then goes to that page.

Old Code

```
           if (typeof $.uniform  === "undefined") {
           } else {
             $.uniform.update("select.jump");
           $("select#mexico").change(function() {
               window.location = $("select#mexico option:selected").val();
            });

            $("select#paris").change(function() {
                window.location = $("select#paris option:selected").val();
            });

            $("select#london").change(function() {
                window.location = $("select#london option:selected").val();
            });

            $("select#jumpMenu").change(function() {
                window.location = $("select#jumpMenu option:selected").val();
            });
        }
```

New Code

```
             if (typeof $.uniform  === "undefined") {
             } else {
        $.uniform.update("select.jump");
           $(this).change(function() {
               window.location = $(this).val();

            });
        }
```

Comment: "let me know if its done correctly" --- does it work as expected? If yes - then yes, it's been done correctly. PS: there are `!=` and `!==` in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/deerua/yw52u/)

html:

```
<select>
    <option val="#">---</option>
    <option val="#paris">paris</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select>
    <option val="#">---</option>
    <option val="#mexico">mexico</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select>
    <option val="#">---</option>
    <option val="#london">london</option>
</select>
```

​js:

```
//if (typeof $.uniform  !== "undefined") {
    //$.uniform.update("select.jump");
    $("select").each(function(){
        $(this).change(function() {
            alert($(this).find("option:selected").val());
            window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        });
    });
//}​​
```

uncomment your function parts

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with jQuery, but instead of the empty block I'd invert the condition:

```
if (typeof $.uniform !== "undefined") {
    $.uniform.update("select.jump");
    $(this).change(function() {
       window.location = $(this).val();
    });
}
```

It's definitely more readable. Or you can use a guard clause if it is in a function:

```
if (typeof $.uniform === "undefined") {
    return;
}
$.uniform.update("select.jump");
$(this).change(function() {
   window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

(References: *Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code*; [Flattening Arrow Code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html))

Comment: I did invert the condition.  That makes sense. Also thanks for the link about flattening code.  I didn't know I had a problem until I read the article.  :)